# How to post multiple form variables appropriately in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I am making a request to a server (which will remained unnamed for privacy reasons) The url takes an email which is used to echo form variable parameters you pass it. My problem is that I am not sure the most efficient way to do this. So here's one way I do it that passes only one form variable, but I am not sure of an approach how to send multiple form variables:

```
NSData * postData;

    NSString * postLength;



    NSString * sample= @"helloWorld";

  //Need help here. How would I go about dynamiaclly adding multiple form vars?
    NSString * token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@,",sample];

    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache]removeAllCachedResponses];

    postData = [token dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dbUrl]];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"Server Request : %@ ",request);

    NSError *error1;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    returning the data in a urlData object
    NSData *urlData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error1];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Token Response : %@ ",responseString);
```

I then realize that another way to do it is use the coco pod AFNetworking. AFNetworking has an option, and it works just how I want it to! The problem is that the method it uses is depreciated. I had to hack it to work it the way I want it to, but here is the method I call to make it happen.

```
  UITextField * username = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

         UITextField *password = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"ME:": username.text, @"MY Message": password.text};
        NSString * txt = username.text;

[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:dbUrl parameters:parameters];
```

This is the depreciated method inside of the AFSerialization.h

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                               URLString:(NSString *)URLString
                              parameters:(id)parameters ;
```

Hopefully I am clear for everyone to understand my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988261/how-to-send-http-post-request-to-php-service-with-objective-c/24988594#249885940) question. It could help to understand the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily append more post variable:

```
NSString * token = 
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",sample, pass];
```